# What is the scope of XACT_ABORT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, scope, sqltransaction, xact-abort

What is the scope of a SET XACT_ABORT statement in SQL Server 2005? i.e.:begin-end block, procedure or trigger, connection, database, server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technet [Using Options in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191203%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) hints that all SET options are scoped at connection or batch level.

MSDN [SET Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) adds details:

> If a SET statement is run in a stored procedure or trigger, the value
>   of the SET option is restored after control is returned from the
>   stored procedure or trigger. Also, if a SET statement is specified in
>   a dynamic SQL string that is run by using either sp_executesql or
>   EXECUTE, the value of the SET option is restored after control is
>   returned from the batch specified in the dynamic SQL string.

It's also possible to enable XACT_ABORT by default for all users via [user options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
EXEC sp_configure 'user options', 16384
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

It can also be enforced for selected users only via custom [logon trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

See also important details on [XACT_ABORT behaviour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128535/in-what-cases-a-transaction-can-be-committed-from-inside-the-catch-block-when-xa/128923#128923).